# Let $\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$. Find $\int_\gamma \big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big)^n\,dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$. Find $\int_\gamma \big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big)^n\,dz$.

So by substituting, I end up with

$$\int_0^{2\pi} i(e^{-it}+1)^ne^{it} \, dt.$$

However, using Cauchy's integral formula, I get just the $(n-1)$th derivative of $z^n$ which is $n!z$ so is the final answer just $2\pi i n$?

Comment: Well, the $\;(n-1)\,$-th derivative of $\;z^n\;$ at $\;z=1\;$ .... times $\;2\pi i\;$ and divided by $\;(n-1)!\;$  . Can't you just use directly Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: Yes, so is my answer of $2\pi i n$ correct? @DonAntonio

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Expanding your integrand by the binomial theorem, the $e^{0it}$ coefficient finishes the proof.

Comment: @J.G. wow! i honestly thought of invoking binomial too...

Comment: Then you have good instincts. Contour integration can often work by simple ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy's integral formula, if $\gamma(t):=1+e^{it}$, then

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\bigg( \frac{z}{z-1}\bigg)^ndz&=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\bigg(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} z^n\bigg)\bigg\vert_{z=1}\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}n!z\bigg\vert_{z=1}\\
&=2\pi i n.
\end{align}